# Will this vintage style LED shock me

Tags: electrical

I have broken the glass globe on a vintage style LED light bulb and the LEDs are still illuminated. If I touch the illuminated LEDs will they electrocute me?

Comment: Can you post a photo of your broken light?

Comment: you said nothing about the lamp, so yes, you  will get electrocuted

Comment: Unlikely you'll be "electrocuted" which means death.  More likely a nasty shock, but why just not take the chance and buy a new bulb?

Comment: Safe way to test is a multimeter. If you decide to use your fingers to test, please record it as a safety lesson for everyone else.

Comment: Don't touch that.

Comment: Were you one of those kids that touched a red hot burner after your mom said not to?  Why would you touch this?

Comment: Don't touch. it was a commercial product, thus there no reason to assume that the insides are isolated fro live wires, isolation costs money.

Answer (score 1):

Also - beware that (depending on how things are wired), you may end up with the bulk of the LED assembly sitting on the 'live' potential, meaning that any exposed conductive bit will be at 110 / 230V AC relative to GND. If you're holding on to something properly grounded with the other hand, that *can potentially be lethal*.

In theory everything exposed should be connected to GND, but traditional light bulbs only have two terminals. One is Neutral and the other is Live. There are conventions for keeping them apart, but they're not always respected.